# Flutter screen navigating back when updating firestore document

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation-drawer

I'm have successfully displayed list of users in ListView using StreamBuilder. But when I'm updating user document in firestore, screen in my mobile app is automatically navigating back.

This is my screens flow. Login -> Home -> ManageUsers -> UserDetails.
By using below code, I created a list in Manage Users screen. Now I'm trying to update user first name in firebase console. After updating the data ManageUsers screen is closing.
[Screen Rec](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8g5g.gif)

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new StreamBuilder(
      stream: Firestore.instance.collection('users').snapshots(),
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData)
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        if (snapshot.hasError)
          return Center(child: new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'));
        final int itemsCount = snapshot.data.documents.length;
        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.none:
            // TODO: Handle this case.
            return new CircularProgressIndicator();
            break;
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
            // TODO: Handle this case.
            return new CircularProgressIndicator();
            break;
          default:
            return new ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: itemsCount,
              addAutomaticKeepAlives: true,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                final DocumentSnapshot document =
                    snapshot.data.documents[index];

                return new ListTile(
                  title: new Text(document['first_name']),
                  subtitle: new Text(document['last_name']),
                  onTap: () => {openUserDetailsScreen(document, context)},
                );
              },
            );
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

Actually it should refresh the data in the same screen instead of navigating back. Am I doing anything wrong in building the list.

Home Screen Code

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  HomeScreen({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomeScreenState createState() => _MyHomeScreenState();

}

class _MyHomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        leading: Builder(
          builder: (context) =>
              IconButton(
                icon: new Icon(Icons.menu),
                onPressed: () => Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer(),
              ),
        ),
      ),
      drawer: MyDrawer(widget.title),
      body: Center(
        child: Text("Home Screen"),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    print('in home page ${globals.loggedInUser.firstName}');
  }
}
```

From home page I'm navigating to ManageUsers screen via drawer. Here is the code for drawer.

```
class MyDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  MyDrawer(this.currentPage);

  final String currentPage;

  bool isAdmin = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var currentDrawer = Provider.of<DrawerStateInfo>(context).getCurrentDrawer;
    return Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          _CustomListTile(
              currentPage, globals.HOME_MENU_TITLE, currentDrawer),
          _CustomListTile(
              currentPage, globals.LOGIN_MENU_TITLE, currentDrawer),
          ConditionalBuilder(
            condition: isAdmin,
            builder: (context) => _CustomListTile(currentPage,
                globals.MANAGE_USERS_MENU_TITLE, currentDrawer),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _CustomListTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final String currentPage;
  final String tileTitle;
  final currentDrawer;

  _CustomListTile(this.currentPage, this.tileTitle, this.currentDrawer);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
        title: Text(
          tileTitle,
          style: currentDrawer == 1
              ? TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)
              : TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
        ),
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
          if (this.currentPage == tileTitle) return;
          Provider.of<DrawerStateInfo>(context).setCurrentDrawer(1);

          switch (tileTitle) {
            case globals.HOME_MENU_TITLE:
              {
                Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) => HomeScreen(
                          title: globals.HOME_MENU_TITLE,
                        )));
                break;
              }

            case globals.LOGIN_MENU_TITLE:
              {
                Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) => LoginScreen(
                          title: globals.LOGIN_MENU_TITLE,
                        )));
                break;
              }

            case globals.MANAGE_USERS_MENU_TITLE:
              {
                Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/ManageUsers");
                break;
              }
            default:
              {
                break;
              }
          }
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: how do you navigate on this flow, are you pushing into a Navigator?

Comment: @haroldolivieri i am using pushNamed `Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/ManageUsers");`

Comment: can you provide the code in Home?

Comment: I've added code to my question. I'm navigating to ManageUsers screen via drawer. I also included code for this.

Answer (score 0):

ListView StreamBuilder means it will listening to your collection.
Please remove the listener when you move to next screen.

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code looks wrong to me:

```dart
Provider.of<DrawerStateInfo>(context).setCurrentDrawer(1);
```

You should have something like an enum or even the tileTitle to use as the saved state for the currently selected option on the drawer, otherwise, you only know there is a selected option, but not exactly which one.

This leads you to this crazy behavior of calling incorrect routes.

Try something like this

```dart
class MyDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  MyDrawer(this.currentPage);

  final String currentPage;

  bool isAdmin = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          _CustomListTile(currentPage, globals.HOME_MENU_TITLE),
          _CustomListTile(currentPage, globals.LOGIN_MENU_TITLE),
          isAdmin
              ? _CustomListTile(currentPage, globals.MANAGE_USERS_MENU_TITLE)
              : Container(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _CustomListTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final String currentPage;
  final String tileTitle;

  _CustomListTile(
    this.currentPage,
    this.tileTitle,
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<DrawerStateInfo>(
      builder: (context, draweStateInfo, _) {

        final currentSelectedItem = draweStateInfo.getCurrentDrawer();

        return ListTile(
            title: Text(
              tileTitle,
              style: currentSelectedItem == tileTitle
                  ? TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)
                  : TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
            ),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();

              if (currentSelectedItem == tileTitle) return;
              draweStateInfo.setCurrentDrawer(tileTitle);

              switch (currentSelectedItem) {
                case globals.HOME_MENU_TITLE:
                  {
                    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (BuildContext context) => HomeScreen(
                          title: globals.HOME_MENU_TITLE,
                        )));
                    break;
                  }

                case globals.LOGIN_MENU_TITLE:
                  {
                    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (BuildContext context) => LoginScreen(
                          title: globals.LOGIN_MENU_TITLE,
                        )));
                    break;
                  }

                case globals.MANAGE_USERS_MENU_TITLE:
                  {
                    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/ManageUsers");
                    break;
                  }
                default:
                  {
                    break;
                  }
              }
            });
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: There is some problem in my code. As I'm new to flutter, I'm following some random tutorial. Somewhere I run into this issue. Now I revamped my code so everything is working fine now.

Comment: But now you’re saving the current drawer correctly?